# quadratic function to get a value (percentage) based on the difference between two points.

Tags: functions, exponential-function

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

> Given a position $y$ between $y_{min}$ and $y_{max}$, I want to calculate a value $x$ between $x_{min}$ and $x_{max}$ where $x$ increases exponentially based on the $y$

I've managed to do the linear conversion as a function (below) getting the value of $x$ based on the percentage distance between $y_{min}$ and $y_{max}$ but don't seem to know where to start to convert it to a quadratic(?) function.

$$
  x = 1 - \frac{(y - y_{min})}{(y_{max} - y_{min})}) *
 (x_{max} - x_{min}) +
 x_{min}
$$

I'm not massively bothered at the moment by the exact shape of the curve but something along the lines of:

$$
x = y \rightarrow x = (\frac{y}{2})^2
$$

I'm sure it's probably more simple than I am trying to make it but I'm stuck!

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out where to put the change...

$$
  x = 1 - ((\frac{(y - y_{\min})}{(y_{\max} - y_{\min})}) / 2) ^ 2 *
 (x_{\max} - x_{\min}) +
 x_{\min}
$$

where using $x^{1 / 2}$ inverses the curve.